# Text array of integers for joining tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, casting, inner-join

I have two tables

1. Entity
2. House

In house table, there is a column entity_id of type text.
And entity_id will store multiple house ids.

So it will look like

```
entity_id (text)
------------------
[1,2]
[3,6]
```

Now I have to join this entity table with house table.
How will I achieve this.
I know this may not be a good design. Though now this my responsibility to do this.

Comment: If you want to do that, you made a mistake modeling that as an array.

Comment: `In house table, there is a column entity_id of type text. And entity_id will store multiple house ids.` It's of type `text` or `text[]`? Just wondering if it's an actual array of ids, or a json array stored as text.

Comment: Can you show the actual DDL?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE entity(
  id integer,
  entity_id integer[],
  details text
);

CREATE TABLE houses(
  id integer,
  house_name text
);

INSERT INTO entity(id, entity_id, details)
VALUES
(1, '{1,3}', 'Left side houses'),
(2, '{2,4}', 'Right side houses');

INSERT INTO houses(id, house_name)
VALUES
(1, 'Left 1'),
(2, 'Right 1'),
(3, 'Left 2'),
(4, 'Right 2');

----------------------------------------------
SELECT h.id as house_id, h.house_name, e.details
FROM houses h
LEFT JOIN entity e 
ON h.id = ANY(e.entity_id);
```

```
| house_id | house_name | details           |
| -------- | ---------- | ----------------- |
| 1        | Left 1     | Left side houses  |
| 2        | Right 1    | Right side houses |
| 3        | Left 2     | Left side houses  |
| 4        | Right 2    | Right side houses |
```

Comment: If I've understood the OP correctly, it's the `houses` table that has an `entity_id` column which contains multiple `entity` ids, not the `entity` table.

Comment: Just a cautionary note...  for non-equality joins (greater than, between, etc), I've noticed it essentially does a cross-join/filter behind the scenes, which is murder on the database for even moderately large objects.  I've never tested this on an `any` but my guess would be the same.  Worth testing, and what works cleanly on sample data may be a lot messier on production data.  $0.02.

Answer (score 1):

As Laurenz says in comment: it seems to be an error of modelisation here.

So I will not directly answer to the question but I will give a most correct structure :

```
CREATE TABLE entity (id int primary key);
CREATE TABLE house (id int primary key);
CREATE TABLE entity_house (id bigserial, identity int references entity(id), idhouse int references house(id));

INSERT INTO entity VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO house VALUES (3), (56);
INSERT INTO entity_house (identity, idhouse) VALUES (1,56), (2,56);

SELECT e.*, h.*
FROM entity_house eh
    INNER JOIN entity e ON eh.identity = e.id
    INNER JOIN house h ON eh.idhouse = h.id;
```